# Why doesn't a lens after a diffraction grating affect the optical path difference?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, diffraction, lenses

When observing interference fringes one often uses a lens after the diffraction grating to focus the fringes on a screen like this:

[image]

At first sight, one might think that after the lens the path difference between the rays is altered.

I think this is not the case, but don't see a clear argument why.

Maybe one could apply Fermat's principle, but this - as far as I know - is restricted to the situation that we compare the path from a point A to a point B (in this case P). But here we start with parallel rays and not from a single point A.

So, is it right, that it doesn't alter the optical path difference and how to explain exactly why?

Comment: Consider that one is placing the lens in the right position to image the plane of the diffraction grating onto the plane of the screen. Is there a shift in the position P of a diffraction minima/maxima compared to not having the lens? Well, yes there is.

Comment: hint: what happens when $d\sin\theta = m\lambda$, $m=0,1,2,...$?